# Websphere - frequent thread/heap dump generation

Tags: jvm, websphere, heap-memory, heap-dump, thread-dump

Our application in prod environment is generating frequent heap/thread dumps while running very large reports eventually resulting in JVM failure. WebSphere is the server and heap size is set to 1024/2048(initial/max) across all nodes.

What are some ways to tackle this issue? I could think about the following options. Is there anything else I am missing?

1. Set min/max heap size to 2048 or even higher?
2. Enable verbose garbage collection in WebSphere and analyze optimal heap size?

> Thread Analysis:
>   Runnable : 123(67%)
>   Blocked : 16(9%)
>   Waiting on Condition : 43(23%)

Comment: You've tagged this with webphere-mq but I don't see any mention of MQ in the question. Should you be tagging with something for App Server experts to see this question?

Comment: What does the dump record as the trigger for dump creation? OutOfMemoryError?

Comment: @MoragHughson: Thanks for the pointer, it was supposed to be websphere and not websphere-mq.

Comment: @TimMcCormick : yes its out of memory error.

Answer (score 0):

A good starting place to start investigating the OOM is [this IBM KnowledgeCenter topic](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27021664)

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems you experience an OutOfMemory Issue there are three possibilities to consider:

- Your Apps consistently need more memory to handle the current load.

**Solution**: You have to **load test** you application with production-like traffic and tune your Min/Max Heap Size accordingly.

- You have a Memory Leak issue.

**Solution**: Analyze the heapdumps/coredumps produced using **[IBM Support Assistant tools](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/support/isa/teamserver.html)**. A PMR to IBM would help.

- Websphere has a memory leak.

**Solution**: Open a PMR

Here is a [nice read](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/httpserv/cookbook/Java.html) about Java Memory Management in WAS environments.

Answer (score 0):

Try to capture the memory, garbage collection information from the production environment. I am not sure if GC log has any performance impact. However, jstat is an extremely light weight tool and can be used in production environment with out any performance impact. Dump the output of jstat at regular intervals using the following command (Here I am setting the interval to 1 hour):

```
jstat -gc <PID> 3600s
```